# Can a programming language be designed to use a fixed amount of memory?

Tags: programming-languages, memory-management, stacks

I have been toying around with the idea of creating a programming language as a side-project, specifically trying to get extreme performance out of a machine.

I have been thinking about the efficiency-memory tradeoff, and was wondering if it would be at all possible to design a language which always uses a fixed amount of memory.
That is, it allocates a large chunk of memory (16K, 64K, 1M, depending on the task), and instead of allocating from a heap, just gives some more memory out of the block we've already allocated.

The idea here is not to be practical, but rather to pose a challenge: design a fast algorithm that works on a fixed amount of memory.

If this sounds like a fun project, please let me know and I'll get on it.

If, however, this is a very naive thing to say (I don't know much about the inner workings of programming languages), I would very much appreciate some resources as to where I can learn more.

Comment: There are problem instances with sizeable input.

Comment: C and asm code written for embedded systems is often written in a way that uses no dynamic memory allocation at all.

Comment: Your system which allocates memory from a 16K chunk instead of allocating from a heap is called... a heap.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph of your question, a more interesting project, IMHO, is designing a programming language that helps programmers to predict the amount of memory that a program will use. The amount depends on input data, of course. I heard that Rust is such a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. At least one variant of C supports this. Its call stacks are bounded in size: you can't call functions within functions indefinitely. It is used for embedded devices.

Comment: In fact all variants of C work the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

There is No need to create a new language. Use as example c. Get a chunk of memory with malloc() and do wharever you wish with it.

On a typical operating system today you might need to use low level OS functions of you want to keep the memory from beeing swapped due to virtual memory.

Comment: With this approach, it may still be very hard to prove that your program never uses more than a given amount of memory. (It's undecidable in general.) E.g. you have to prove nested function calls cannot nest deeper than a certain bound. You need certain constraints on how functions can be called before you can prove this for every case.